# move_uploaded_file doesnt work

Tags: php, file, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image via a PHP script.

In the script all conditions are true while I upload the image but move_uploaded_file function doesn't seem to work.

What may be the problem?

My HTML code is

```
<form id="register_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-
data">
Select image to Upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "/home/infibusiness1/Desktop/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], 
$target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has   
been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
echo "<br>File Name : ".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
}
}
?>
```

Comment: have you tried changing upload directory to something else?

Comment: yes  i have changed first directory does not have permissions to be written so i changed it to desktop location

Comment: your server running on localhost.

Comment: plus in that question the person is using windows and i m using linux thats the reason i cant use that solution.

Comment: Ok, agreed. I have deleted my comment. Note that your question does not mention your operating system anywhere. But still there are hundreds of questions on this topic on Stackoverflow. Please be so kind as to search first next time. Thank you.

Comment: yes for sure. Thanks @e4c5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the web server has write permission on the target directory?
You will need to know what user the web server is running as or if security isn't a concern try

```
chmod 777 /home/infibusiness1/Desktop/uploads/
```